# How to use structs declared private?

Tags: c++, private

I'm working on a project with a pre-made .hpp file with all the declarations and stuff.

A struct is declared in the private part of the class, along with some private members.

I need to create an array with the type of the struct in my .cpp file.

```
//.hpp

private:
     struct foo
     {
          std::string a;
          unsigned int b;
     };

     std::string* x;
     unsigned int y;

//.cpp

unsigned int returny()
{
     return y;    // No errors
}

foo newArray[10]; // Compile time error; unknown type name
```

Why is it that I can return y, which is also private, but not make an array out of the struct foo?

How can I fix this? (I'm in an introductory C++ class... so hopefully there's a simple solution)

Comment: Please paste complete reproducible code...

Comment: If `newArray` is inside a member function, you should not get that error. Please post a complete example. If it's not inside a member function, you're probably doing it wrong. (If it's an introductory C++ class and you were given the header, you're supposed to complete the exercise *without* creating an array of the struct outside the class.)

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of issues.

1. You can't use a type that's defined in the `private` section of class like you are trying.
2. The nested type can be used by specifying the appropriate scope.

   ```
   EnclosingClass::foo newArray[10];
   ```

   But this will work only if `foo` is defined in the `public` section of `EnclosingClass`.

Answer (score 2):

you should define the struct int the outside of the class like this

```
struct Foo
     {
          std::string a;
          unsigned int b;
     };

class A {
private:
Foo foo;
...
}
```